# Can not select _PARTIONTIME in SELECT but can select it in INSERT

Tags: google-bigquery

When running the below `SELECT` I get this error message

> Error: Invalid field name "_PARTITIONTIME". Field names are not allowed to start with the (case-insensitive) prefixes _PARTITION, *TABLE*, *FILE* and _ROW_TIMESTAMP

```
SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME,
    jobId
FROM
    `project.dataset.audit`
WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME >= TIMESTAMP("2019-02-20")
```

However, when I use it in a DML the query is working

```
INSERT INTO
  `project.dataset.audit_clustered`
  (
      _PARTITIONTIME,
      jobId,
  )
SELECT
    _PARTITIONTIME,
    jobId
FROM
    `project.dataset.audit`
WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME >= TIMESTAMP("2019-02-20")
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the `SELECT` alone is not working
2. Is it guarantee that the `INSERT` will work properly and data will be inserted to the correct partition of the target table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT  _PARTITIONTIME
```

With

```
SELECT  _PARTITIONTIME AS something
```

This because the resulting set can't have a column starting with `_`, but you can name it anything else.

Comment: Thanks, @Felipe, So you are saying the `INSERT` command doesn't care about the _ like the `SELECT`? Can I assume all partitions will be inserted to their correct place in the destination table? I have to say this is a bit of a confusing and unexpected behaviour between `SELECT` and `INSERT`

Comment: _PARTITIONTIME is a reserved keyword for BigQuery, so it won't let you create a table with a column named like that (same as a resulting set)... but it will let you use it when appropriate